# Get data from database not from form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I'm having a problem when trying to compare a data database, with data input by form.
I have a `"pedido"`, this has many `"items"`. I need compare `"item"` by `"item"` if this is modifies in the form.
Then I need get original data from database and data modified from form.
The problem is when i try get original data from database. 
Always get the data modified by form.
How Can i get the original data from database after the submit the form?

NOTE: i have tried get `PedidoAuxiliar` before and after HandleRequest.This doesn´t work!

UPDATE CODE: Input how compare the `items`

This is my controller editAction:

```
public function editarAction(Request $request, $id)
    {    
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $pedido = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);
        //$pedidoAuxiliar = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);
        $formulario = $this->createForm(new PedidoType(), $pedido, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('my_routing', array('id' => $id)),
            'attr' => array(
                'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
            ),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
        $formulario->handleRequest($request);

        if($formulario->isValid()){
            $pedidoAuxiliar = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);

            foreach($pedido->getArticulos() as $articulo){

            foreach($pedidoAuxiliar->getArticulos() as $articuloAuxiliar){
                if($articuloAuxiliar->getId() == $articulo->getId()){
                    if($articuloAuxiliar->getCantidad() == $articulo->getCantidad()){
            //Some code...
```

Comment: I believe you should have a look at [Change Tracking Policies](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html)

Comment: The basic problem is that D2 maintains an internal cache of objects so your two queries will always return the exact same object.  You might consider cloning your base object and then comparing.  Or do some of the change tracking stuff that other folks have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from db u can use EntityManager::refresh($entity) its overwrite entity data using db. So u must use data from form, not entity to compare.
But u always can ust Doctrine to check changes eg: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html
because Doctrine hold info about old and new value, but is not so easy to get (outside listeners)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I have created a new connection entity manager in my config.yml.
Now I call my entity data from my new entity manager and i get datas from database! Thanks!